# Whats the difference between "Pods" and "Static Pods" in kubernetes and when to choose "static pods" over regular pods

Tags: kubernetes

New to kubernetes and looking to understand the best practice around using different kubernetes objects and have difficulty understanding what is a major difference between "Pods" and "Static Pods" functionally if there is any ?

Major questions as below :

Question 1: What is a major difference between "Pods" and "Static Pods" functionally if there is any ?

Question 2: When to choose "static pods" over regular pods.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Static pods are pods created and managed by kubelet daemon on a specific node without API server observing them. If the static pod crashes, kubelet restarts them. Control plane is not involved in lifecycle of static pod. Kubelet also tries to create a mirror pod on the kubernetes api server for each static pod so that the static pods are visible i.e., when you do `kubectl get pod` for example, the mirror object of static pod is also listed.

You almost never have to deal with static pods. Static pods are usually used by software bootstrapping kubernetes itself. For example, `kubeadm` uses static pods to bringup kubernetes control plane components like api-server, controller-manager as static pods. `kubelet` can watch a directory on the host file system (configured using `--pod-manifest-path` argument to kubelet) or sync pod manifests from a web url periodically (configured using `--manifest-url` argument to kubelet). When `kubeadm` is bringing up kubernetes control plane, it generates pod manifests for api-server, controller-manager in a directory which kubelet is monitoring. Then kubelet brings up these control plane components as static pods.

Comment: This answer is pretty much a summary of https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/

Answer (score 9):

One of the use case of static pod is kubernetes control plane bootstrapping. Kubeadm while bootstarping a kubernetes cluster creates API Server, controller manager , kube scheduler as a static pod because it can not create these as normal pod due to the fact that kube Api Server itself is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from official documentation link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/

- "POD" life cycle is handled by kubernetes control plane (from cluster master).
- "Static pod" life cycle is in control of "kublet" running on given worker node where it is created and not in control of cluster master.

Reading more i found below on offical docs 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#static-pods

Which answers my Question-2

"when to use static pods" >> "**static pods" are useful in cluster bootstrapping cases**. and a note stating that static Pods may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Where have you found information that static pods may be deprecated? I saw only that a parameter deprecated https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#options:~:text=ignored.%20(DEPRECATED%3A-,This%20parameter%20should%20be%20set%20via%20the%20config%20file%20specified%20by%20the%20Kubelet's%20%60%2D%2Dconfig%60%20flag but not static pod itself