# How to access kube-scheduler on a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kube-scheduler

I'm trying to figure out how to configure the kubernetes scheduler using a custom config but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly how the scheduler is accessible.

The scheduler runs as a pod under the `kube-system` namespace called `kube-scheduler-it-k8s-master`. [The documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/)  says that you can configure the scheduler by creating a config file and calling `kube-scheduler --config <filename>`. However I am not able to access the scheduler container directly as running `kubectl exec -it kube-scheduler-it-k8s-master -- /bin/bash` returns:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```

I tried modifying `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler` to mount my custom config file within the pod and explicitly call `kube-scheduler` with the `--config` option set, but it seems that my changes get reverted and the scheduler runs using the default settings.

I feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamentally about the kubernetes scheduler. Am I supposed to pass in the custom scheduler config from within the scheduler pod itself? Or is this supposed to be done remotely somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you bootstrap your cluster? Did you use something like kubeadm or is it created by a cloud-provider?

Comment: It is an on-prem cluster bootstrapped by kubeadm @ShashankV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your [X problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is "how to modify scheduler configuration", you can try the following for it.

---

#### Using kubeadm

If you are using `kubeadm` to bootstrap the cluster, you can use `--config` flag while running `kubeadm init` to pass a custom configuration object of type `ClusterConfiguration` to pass extra arguments to control plane components.

Example config for scheduler:

```
$ cat sched.conf
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.16.0
scheduler:
  extraArgs:
    address: 0.0.0.0
    config: /home/johndoe/schedconfig.yaml
    kubeconfig: /home/johndoe/kubeconfig.yaml
```

```
$ kubeadm init --config sched.conf
```

You could also try `kubeadm upgrade apply --config sched.conf <k8s version>` to apply updated config on a live cluster.

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/

---

#### Updating [static pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612514/whats-the-difference-between-pods-and-static-pods-in-kubernetes-and-when-to) manifest

You could also edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml`, modify the flags to pass the config. Make sure you mount the file into the pod by updating `volumes` and `volumeMounts` section.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
    - --config=/etc/kubernetes/mycustomconfig.conf
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/mycustomconfig.conf
      name: customconfig
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/mycustomconfig.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: customconfig
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried updating the static pod manifest but my volume with the custom config does not get created for some reason. Only the `kubeconfig` volume gets created.

Comment: EDIT: Looks like I found the issue, [volumes cannot mount onto other volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238854/3654696). I changed the mount directory of the custom config to not overlap with the `scheduler.conf` mount and it works. Thanks!